# Getting 500 Internal serve "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" when trying from browser angular+ spring boot+ jwt

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have issue in using @preAuthorize annotaton when i use this annotation in my get method inside a controller, when i send request from browser i get 500 internal server error "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" but when i send it through postman it is getting 200 ok status with response, please help me identifying the issue.

Angular front end:

```
export class WelcomeservicedataService {


  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute ,private http:HttpClient) { }


  ServiceHelloDatawithpath(name){
   return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/hello-world/${name}`);
  }
```

Subscriber:

```
  Message(){
  this.serverMessage.ServiceHelloDatawithpath(this.Username).subscribe(
  data=> {
    this.message= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).response;
    this.called=true;
  },
  error=>{
  this.message="Only Admin can access";
  this.error=true;
  }
  );
```

Web security configurer

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Value("${jwt.get.token.uri}")
    private String authenticationPath; 


          @Override
          public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService);  // <-- replacing the in-memory anthentication setup
          }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request

        httpSecurity
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                 .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest()
            .authenticated().
            and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/hello-world/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .csrf()                   
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {

        webSecurity
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**") // enables api docs
        .and()
        .ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/**")// enable swagger
        .and()
        .ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**")// enables actuators
        .and()
        .ignoring().antMatchers("/**")
        .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
                authenticationPath)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/products/**" //Other Stuff You want to Ignore
            )
            ;           
    }
}
```

Authorization filter:

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Value("${jwt.http.request.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.debug("Authentication Request For '{}'", request.getRequestURL());

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("JWT_TOKEN_UNABLE_TO_GET_USERNAME", e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.warn("JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRED", e);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT_TOKEN_DOES_NOT_START_WITH_BEARER_STRING");
        }

        logger.debug("JWT_TOKEN_USERNAME_VALUE '{}'", username);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(),
                        userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));


                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
               }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Controller class: trying to hit @GetMapping("hello-world/")

```
package com.luv2code.springboot.thymeleafdemo.controller;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import com.luv2code.springboot.thymeleafdemo.entity.Employee;
import com.luv2code.springboot.thymeleafdemo.entity.StringResponse;
import com.luv2code.springboot.thymeleafdemo.service.EmployeeService;


@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class HelloWorldController {


    private EmployeeService producer; 

    @Autowired
    public HelloWorldController(EmployeeService producer) {

        this.producer = producer;
    }



    @GetMapping("/hello-world/{name}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
    public StringResponse helloworld(@PathVariable String name){
        StringResponse hello= new StringResponse("welcome "+ name);
        return hello;
    }
```

when i'm using postman it works fine! but when i hit the same from broswer i"m getting error.

Error:

```
2020-06-14 20:51:51.309  WARN 18320 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] wtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter : JWT_TOKEN_DOES_NOT_START_WITH_BEARER_STRING
2020-06-14 20:51:51.325 ERROR 18320 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext] with root cause

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.luv2code.springboot.thymeleafdemo.controller.HelloWorldController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a6a708f.helloworld(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at com.luv2code.springboot.thymeleafdemo.jwt.JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Comment: your last if statement should be after `username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);` line and not a separate line, it is working in postman because you are adding `Bearer token` in request header where as when trying from angular httpClient you are not sending anything, also if both the applications are separate then check `cors` config although this has nothing to do with error.

Comment: Thanks silentsudo! i resolved it by myself.

Comment: Please update it as answer so other can benefit from this if they encounter same issue as yours

Comment: I just made in mistake in interceptor added"BearerAuthorization" instead of "Authorization"